# Including data from two models in one table in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I have a React-Rails app, which display Sites, each of which belongs to a Trust.

I am confused how to display data from both models within a single table. In particular, within the table of Sites, I want to include a column for Trust Name for each site.

Within the Site and Trust models, I've included belongs_to and has_many.

When I'm in the Rails console, I can access each site's trust name via site.trust.name.

However, within the SitesController, I'm confused how to access that information within the index action.

Below is the code as it is now:

```
def index
    @sites = Site.all

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.json { render json: @sites }
    end
end
```

However, when I pass @sites to the React app and separate each site out via a map function, it finds site.trust to be undefined.

What should I do to access trust (and trust.name) via @sites?

Comment: Here you just fetch the site recording, you should be using eager loading:
@sites = Site.includes(:trusts)

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, add

```
def index
  @sites = Site.includes(:trust)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render json: @sites }
  end
end
```

Using `includes` avoids N + 1 query issue(querying the database for every `site` object).

For more, see http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes 
and https://www.sitepoint.com/silver-bullet-n1-problem/

And in your view,

```
<% @sites.each do |site| %>
  <!-- display site's properties -->
  <%= site.trust.name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks, Arun! I just tried that, and I'm now getting an error message that "ActiveRecord::AssociationNotFoundError in Sites#index - Association named 'trusts' was not found on Site." However, in my models, Site belongs_to Trust and Trust has_many Sites. Is there somewhere else I need to set up this association?

Comment: My bad. You have the pass the name of the relationship to `includes`. I have updated the answer. I haven't tested it. Let me know if it works.